# Can't switch between ruby versions with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to switch from `ruby 1.9.3` to `2.0.0`.

When I run `rvm alias show default` I get `ruby-2.0.0-p481`

When I run `rvm use default` I get

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
```

Then when I run `ruby -v` I get `ruby 1.9.3p484`

I want to use 2.0.0

`rvm 2.0.0` or `rvm use 2.0.0` do not work either.

Any ideas? THanks!

Comment: Set your terminal to run command as a login shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already fixed the issue, so this is more of information than help, you can also do it by adding following line to you `~/.bashrc`

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

This will permanently fix it.

A temporary one time fix can also be:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

PS: this is basically exactly what you have already done, but from command prompt

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @japed I managed to solve the issue following the guide [here](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal).

I had to check the 'Run command as login shell' checkbox on the Title and Command tab of gnome-terminal's Edit ▸ Profile Preferences dialog. Like here:
[image]